# jquery autocomplete plugin dose not work in masterpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, master-pages

I,ve been working on a autoparts website where i needed autocomplete functionality in the search box .

things i have already tried:

i)[ i have tried working with ajax extender using services no luck ]
ii)[ i have also tried jquery ui builtin autocomplete plugin no luck]

but after one day of full struggle i finally  got it working on the simple aspx page but when i use this code in to the masterpage it just dosent work.

on this part i need u guys :)

```
//code inside the masterpage head
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ctl00_myTextBox").autocomplete('select.ashx');
    });
 </script>
```

//NOTE: this textbox is also in the masterpage not in any contentpage

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Width="250" ></asp:TextBox>
```

//this is code of httphandler ...
//NOTE: i am using LuceneIndexes to retrive the data

public class select : IHttpHandler
    {

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["q"]))
       {
           foreach (string s in GetAutoCompleteValues(context.Request.QueryString["q"]))
           {
               context.Response.Write(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(s)+Environment.NewLine);
           }
       }

    }
    public static string[] GetAutoCompleteValues(string prefixText)
    {
           DataTable dt = GetSearchList.GetResult(prefixText);
           List<string> RowNames = new List<string>();
           foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
           {
               RowNames.Add(drow[1].ToString() + " " + drow[2].ToString() + " " + drow[3].ToString() + " " + drow[4].ToString() + " " + drow[5].ToString() + " " + drow[6]);
           }
           return RowNames.ToArray();
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

please help me out any suggesstions will be helpful thanx in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because you do not use the dynamic rendered control id, and from the moment you place it on master page, the id is change.

In this line on your javascript, use the `myTextBox.ClientID` as:

```
$("#<%=myTextBox.ClientID%>").autocomplete('select.ashx');
```

to make dynamic render of the control id, and make jQuery finds it.